# Laravel, unknown error after deploy to LIFE server, 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-8

I just deployed a laravel 8 project from my local server to a LIFE server, everything went OK apparently, I managed to run composer successfully (`composer update`), composer doesn't throw any error message, the domain of the LIFE server is linked with the folder `/project/public`. I have also managed to run `php artisan migrate` with success, I can see the tables created by artisan in the database, so the application is correctly connected with the database.

I have also changed the permissions of the main project folder to 755 and the permission of the storage folder to 777.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./storage
sudo chmod -R 777 ./bootstrap/cache/
sudo chmod -R 664 /mainprojectfolder
```

I successfully generate a new KEY with artisan, and I managed to clear the cache with artisan... In other words, I have been through all the tutorials that I found online, but the problem is not resolved.

```
php artisan key:generate
```

I have also managed to clear the project cache as the official documentation suggests with:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache
```

I have also created the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I browser the server URL, I see that the browser is correctly redirecting to domain/login, which is correct, as long as I am not logged in the application redirects to the login page. Then the browser displays the classic: `500 Internal Server Error - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request...`

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the server logs because the server is a shared virtual server, so I can't figure out what the problem exactly is.

Can you guys please suggest?

Comment: Have you checked laravel's storage/logs files?

Comment: yes I have, there is no error related to that, actually, there are no errors at all since I migrated the website and since I cleaned the cache. I can't find a solution, I think it's a server issue, I will try to migrate the project into another more expensive server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found the solution after a lot of attempts, the `.htaccess` file was wrong and I swapped:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

with:

```
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

I added the `/` before index.php. This has fixed the problem.

Comment: Run into this just today, it was exactly my problem and it's now solved. Thank you man.

Comment: I deployed it my laravel-app (version 10) 
and worked perfect, thanks.

Comment: Confirmed this also fixed the same problem. Laravel 9

Answer (score 0):

I added the / before index.php in the folder public. This has fixed the problem.